# DynamoDB: get one record yielding a list VS get multiple records

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering if there is a non-negligible performance difference for a **get** operation in the following two scenarios:

1. Each entry is identified by one key field and contains a list/set of objects representing sub-entries. The get operation returns one record for one key, and this record contains a list with multiple sub-records.
2. Instead of having a list of sub-entries, each is identified by a composite key and is inserted as a regular entry. Then the get operation returns multiple records for one key.

**sub-question**. If my context is as follows, which approach is likely to be more efficient for me? i) My items are identified by a primary key and a secondary one; ii) each item is inserted individually every time; iii) the only retrieval operation type consists of getting all entries for a primary key; iv) there will be quite a lot more retrieval operations then writing ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you always get the all the sub-records for an entry then on the read side there is basically no difference. In the single entry approach you would just get the item. On the multiple sub-records you would use a query to return all of them at once.

However if you are for example continuously adding new sub-records and only need to read a subset (e.g. the newest, or ones from a date range) sub-records can be more read efficient.

For writes, depending on how many sub-records there are using sub-records can be more write efficient also. Once the total size of the sub records exceeds 1k you will be more efficient to write them individually.

Calling the Get API costs you .5 RCU per 4k based on the item size.

Calling the Query API costs you .5 RCU per 4k read from the table.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, you are saying that get(key) returning only one item containing a set costs the same as get(key) returning multiple items with no sets? In other words: 1) get(key) returns 1 result yielding a set with 999 items; 2) get(key) returns 1000 results yielding no sets; these two scenarios cost the same?

Comment: Basically. To be completely clear you get(key) one record, and query(partition key) to get many (not multiple gets which costs more). but if they return the same size data they cost the same.

Comment: I implemented a very small test using com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded.DynamoDBEmbedded. Aparently, QueryRequest() took one order of magnitude longer to return 10000 results comparing to GetItemRequest() returning 1 result with a list containing 10000 entries. How does this compare to your answer?

Comment: Re-run your test and return the consumed read capacity. Also how many pages did the 10000 item query use?

Comment: GET: CapacityUnits: 21.0;  QUERY: CapacityUnits: 127.0: by pages do you mean getQueryResult.getCount()? If so it is 10000

Comment: No. Pages would be the number of pages/api calls needed to return all the records for that query. Some SDK will perform the pagination automatically.

Comment: The 10000 results fit in just one page

Comment: Can you add a sample of a couple items from the list and the corresponding records?

Comment: The list is composed of small dummy Strings, e.g. "dummy11"

Comment: And how large is the partition and sort key for the individual records?

Comment: Partition key about 10B, sort key about 35B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192590/discussion-between-cementblocks-and-joao-matos).